# Builder pattern & failling

Tags: java, solid-principles, builder-pattern

Consider the following class:

```
@Getter
public class EmailVO {
    private final Long id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String email;
    private final String address;

    @Slf4j
    @Component
    @Scope("prototype")
    public static class Builder {
        private Lead lead;

        private Long id;
        private String firstName;
        private String email;
        private String address;

        public Builder fromLead(Lead lead) {
            this.lead = lead;
            return this;
        }

        public EmailVO build() {
            if (lead == null) {
                log.error("Failed to build EmailVO: lead was not initialized");
                return new EmailVO(this);
            }

            User user = lead.getUser();
            id = user.getId();
            firstName = user.getFirstName();
            email = user.getEmail();
            address = user.getAddress();

            return new EmailVO(this);
        }
    }

    private EmailVO(Builder builder) {
        id = builder.id;
        firstName = builder.firstName;
        email = builder.email;
        address = builder.address;

        if (id == null ||
            firstName == null ||
            email == null ||
            address == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(); // Maybe some ohter Unchecked Exception would be better
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, this would be a proper VO class implementation which only permits to build new instances from it's builder, which also follows adequately the builder pattern (correct me if I'm wrong).

From a SOLID perspective, this code is fine as the builder single responsibility is aggregating data to build `EmailVO` and it's constructor will take care of letting only valid instances of it to come to life.

Now, if you care for code cluttering and readability (imagine a much bigger VO for the case), the builder could fail when one tries to build without required parameters initialized instead of letting the object's constructor to fail which can potentially remove many null checks inside the constructor. In the example code, if `lead` field is `null` this one validation could throw an exception instead of letting `EmailVO`'s constructor to check for integrity despite being the constructor's responsibility.

**Would it be OK to remove the validation from the constructor of `EmailVO` and letting the builder to take care of it?** Consider that in this case the constructor is `private` making it invisible to the outside of this class.

This seems like going against SOLID despite that if the builder is not validating required parameters it can fail in it's one responsibility which is to aggregate required data to build an `EmailVO` instance.

Yet, an idea that crossed my mind is having a flag as member field of the `EmailVO.Builder` class to signalize if it succeed or not in aggregating the required parameters and then `EmailVO`'s constructor could only check (and trust) this flag.

Comment: Considering your  `EmailVO` is strictly for holding variables, I'd say it should have zero logic.

Comment: in your EmailVO constructor, consider replacing `x = builder.x; if (x == null) {}` with `x = Objects.requireNonNull(builder.x);`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Good point. VO objects should be used just to carry values, not to validate them, but wouldn't it be against SOLID to let a builder perform such validation? One could say that you can let alone all the needed validation to occur in an isolated method (inside a Controller or such), but that would allow the builder to build partially constructed objects, would that be against the builder pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your `EmailVO` is strictly for holding values,
I suggest that you minimize the login in the setters and constructor (variation of the @Christopher Schneider comment).

If you want validation,
you might add a validation method to the `EmailVO` object.

About the "build with bad values" question, add that validation to the builder.

The `EmailVO` validation might include something like "is this a validly constructed email address".

Also, don't pass the builder to the `EmailVO` object, just have a package access constructor that is used by the builder.  Be sure that the builder is in the same package as the `EmailVO` object.

Comment: _If you want validation, you might add a validation method to the EmailVO object._ Sure, when I say validation I mean it for checking if required parameters are present, not semantics and consistency validation. But about _About the "build with bad values" question, add that validation to the builder._ this is exactly what I want to do, but isn't this against SOLID? This is what I am unsure about.

Comment: I don't see where the builder would break SOLID.  Specifically, the responsibility of the builder is to construct a valid `EmailVO`.  That means that the builder is responsible to prevent construction of bad `EmailVO` objects.

Comment: Is the builder responsible for preventing the construction of bad objects? Isn't it responsible for aggregating parameters for an object construction? As you say it I am reading it like this: _A builder is responsible for aggregating parameters for building an object **and** to prevent construction of malformed instances of this object_

Comment: The builder makes this claim "I R MAKE GUD STUFF"  or "I will produce a good object".  That makes it the responsibility of the builder to produce a good object.  Good in this case, includes valid values.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to eleminate a lot of boilerplate. Perhaps [immmutables](https://immutables.github.io/) would be a good fit.

[Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/) creates boilerplate at compile time via an annotation processor and has a convenient way to create a pojo with a fluent builder.

From the landing page:

```
// Define an abstract value type
@Value.Immutable
public interface ValueObject {
  String name();
  List<Integer> counts();
  Optional<String> description();
}

// Then use generated immutable implementation
ValueObject valueObject =
    ImmutableValueObject.builder()
        .name("My value")
        .addCounts(1)
        .addCounts(2)
        .build();
```

Comment: This puts away my problem for sure, but I still wanna know about what is best to do in this situation in respect to SOLID. Anyway it is great to know about Immutables. Thanks!